# How do I jump naturally while keeping gravity constant?

Tags: actionscript-3, gravity

I have gravity and jumping "working". When you walk off a platform you fall slowly until you collide with the floor again but the player jump is basically a teleport upward rather than a smooth increase then decrease in altitude.  I've tried combining if statements 1&3/2&4 logically to say player can jump when touching the floor or fall smoothly when they walk off but I end up with an error and my player vanishing from the screen.  My end goal is a smooth jump and smooth fall when walking off platforms (matching speeds).

note: `gravity = 1`, `vertSpeed = Infinity`,

```
    private function checkFalling(newY):void
    {
        var hitFloor:Boolean = HitTest.complexHitTestObject(player, floor, 1);          

        if (hitFloor)
        {
            trace("Grounded");
            vertSpeed = Infinity;
        }

        if (!hitFloor)
        {
            trace("Floating");
            vertSpeed = 1;
            //newY += vertSpeed;
        }

        if (vertSpeed == Infinity)
        {
            if (zKeyPressed)
            {
                vertSpeed = jumpStart;
            }
        }

        if (vertSpeed != Infinity)
        {
            trace("pushing");
            vertSpeed += gravity;
            newY += vertSpeed;
        }

        player.y = newY;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say don't do constant hittest, but that's just me. To make a player jump from hit-floor condition, you need to check `vertSpeed` together with hittest, so if that vertical speed is less than zero, then we are jumping and we ignore that hittest altogether.

```
if (hitFloor)
    if (vertSpeed>0){
        trace("Grounded");
        vertSpeed = Infinity;
    }
// else not grounded, let's fly upwards
```

Comment: I tested that and tried some more work arounds but I still get the jittery teleport jump.  I think it could be due to constantly checking if the player is touching the floor, causing an immediate sharp push down upon jumping or setting vertSpeed to 1 when not touching a floor.

Comment: You should not then set vertSpeed to 1. Otherwise as soon as you've jumped, you're already falling down.